# a question about the sendEvent method of UIApplication

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiapplication

I override the `- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method of UIApplication to handle some touch event.

.h

```
@interface myUIApplication : UIApplication {

}
```

.m

```
@implementation myUIApplication

- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"a event catched");
    [super sendEvent:event];
}

@end
```

and I edit my File's Owner's class to myUIApplication in MainWindow.xib.
But when I touch the screen
There is no output like @"a event catched"

Is there some mistake I have?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to pass `@"myUIApplication"` to `UIApplicationMain` function. So it should be,

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"myUIApplication", nil);
```